# Magento 2: How to add custom attribute in an admin field?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, xml, custom-attributes

I created a new field using the file **system.xml**, but I need to add a custom attribute, for example, `data-mycustomattr="true"`.

You can see an example on this image below, the console shows a custom attribute in the field **Store Name**.

[image: New attribute on Magento 2 admin panel field]

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain in brief?

Comment: custom attribute or custom configuration field in admin configuration?

Comment: Custom attribute